# Maven plugin not running where I want it to

Tags: java, maven, properties, pom.xml

I have a maven project that I want to load properties from a file when things happen.  I've got the codehaus properties-maven-plugin and I need it to run automagically.

If I run `mvn test` or `mvn compile`, the task plugin load the properties file just fine.

I see this in the output:
`[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default)...---`

When I run `mvn flyway:init`, say, I do not see it run and the properties do not get loaded.

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>workflow</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Foo Framework</name>
    <description>Foo framework</description>
    <properties>
        <postgre.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgre.version>
        <flyway.version>2.2.1</flyway.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgre.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>${url}</url>
                    <user>${user}</user>
                    <password>${pass}</password>
                    <locations>
                        <location>classpath:sql/pgsql</location>
                    </locations>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgre.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
      </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>src/main/resources/db.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone suggest what I can do, or some documentation I can read to make this work?  I have read plenty of maven documentation and cannot seem to understand it well enough to make this happen.  I thought what I have here would make it run during the `initialize` phase, but evidently not...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close.  There is a difference between running Maven using a phase, and using a goal.  Start with a quick review of the [Maven lifecycle documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

When you run `mvn compile`, Maven runs all goals bound to the compile phase, plus anything bound to earlier phases.  You have bound the `properties:read-project-properties` goal to the `initialize` phase.  `initialize` is one of the first phases, so read-project-properties executes when `compile`, or `test`, or any of the later phases are used in the command.

When you run `mvn flyway:init`, you are only running a single goal, not the entire lifecycle.  Thus, the only thing that runs with that command is the flyway-maven-plugin's init goal, nothing else.

If you want those two goals to run together, you could try binding the `flyway:init` goal to the `initialize` phase (if that is not the default; I could not tell from reading the plugin's documentation).  Then, `mvn initialize` will run both.

If you don't want to bind `flyway:init` to a phase, then you may run both goals explicitly with `mvn flyway:init initialize`.